# Giving border to <tr> of table in a table

Tags: html, css

How do i give a border to the `<tr>`(t_border).
The inner table shouldnt inherit the style from the outer one

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
           <table class="t_border">
              <tr>
                 <td>B</td>
              </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: table.t_border tr { border : 1px solid #000; } try this one it might helps

Answer (score 1):

You can try as per my code:

```
<style>
    table{
         border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.t_border tr{
         border:solid 1px red;
    }
</style>

  <table>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <table class="t_border">
                  <tr>
                     <td>B</td><td>B</td><td>B</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Hope it might help you!

Answer (score 0):

you can set separate style for the class .t_border, see example code..

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
           <table class="t_border">
              <tr>
                 <td>B</td>
              </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
           </table></td></tr></table>

<style>
    .t_border
    {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

just give style of **`tr`** tag

```
   <tr>
         <td style="border : 1px solid black">B</td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to style your border, you may use other answers.

But if you only need to use the pure HTML table style, you can use this :

`<table border=1>` to give border on your table inside table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a border to a `<tr>`. You would have to add it to the `<td>`s. Also your `t_border` table isn't be being closed `</table>` and your outer table should be closed with `</table>` instead of `</tbody>`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down voted as it is the only one that is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving the border to the tr won't really have an effect. It would be better to give the td's a border top or bottom of what you want it to actually show up. For example, border-bottom:2px solid black;